# How to check activity related with deployment of blueprint in Pegasus

Tags: fiware-pegasus

Can users check their activity related to deployment of blueprints? I mean, how many times a given blueprint has been deployed and similar metrics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pegasus stores in the internal DB all the historical operations that are requested to be done but currently the users do not have the possibility to access this information in order to have a statistical information about the deployment of blueprints and so on, only the administrator of the component can get them.

If you want to know this information you have to contact to the FIWARE Pegasus developer team via fiware-lab-help@lists.fiware.org in order to obtain it.